# New Date() has wrong time in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider:

```
root@ubuntu:/firma/Exotech/heart-beat/heart-beat-service# date
Mon Apr 24 17:07:52 CEST 2017
root@ubuntu:/firma/Exotech/heart-beat/heart-beat-service# node test.js
2017-04-24T15:07:56.271Z
root@ubuntu:/firma/Exotech/heart-beat/heart-beat-service# cat test.js
console.log(new Date())
root@ubuntu:/firma/Exotech/heart-beat/heart-beat-service#
```

As you can see, the server date 17:07, but the new Date() is returning 15:07. How do I correct my Node.js with the server's date settings?

Comment: First one is in your local time zone, the second one is UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want UTC date you can : 
1) decrease the number of hours manually (not recommended)
2) use a lib that does that for you (such as [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) which I recommend, but this is opiniated, so you should do as you want)

Comment: Do you think this solution will give my problems:

now = _ => Date(new Date().toLocaleString())

Comment: It depends.. If you just want to print a string then yes toLocaleString is enough
but if you want to work on the newly created date object, then to LocaleString is not enough since it transforms it into a string, not a DateObject

Answer (score 4):

so I just figured out a good way to do this without using external libraries

```
let now = new Date()
now = now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset())
```

so now will become the correct time, it still understands it as your local datetime so to change to utc string and stuff use the new Date().toUTC....(no need to substract the offset)

Answer (score 2):

The first one, i.e the Linux date command gives the date on your system.
The second one gives the time according to UTC, a time standard that is the basis for civil time and time zones worldwide.

Comment: Do you think this solution will give my problems:

now = _ => Date(new Date().toLocaleString())

Answer (score 0):

The time in nodeJS in UTC/Z format you can convert it in GMT to get the correct Time e.g.
`const UTCTime = new Date() const time = UTCTime.toTimeString()`